# OWA error: Exception type: Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.StorageTransientException

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, exchange, exchange-2007

Some users are receiving this error randomlly at OWA webmail:

```
Request 
Url: https://xxx:443/owa/default.aspx 
User host address: xxx 

Exception 
Exception type: Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.StorageTransientException 
Exception message: There was a problem accessing Active Directory. 

Call stack 
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.ExchangePrincipal.FromUserSid(ADRecipientSession recipientSession, SecurityIdentifier userSid) 
Microsoft.Exchange.Clients.Owa.Core.OwaWindowsIdentity.CreateExchangePrincipal() 
Microsoft.Exchange.Clients.Owa.Core.RequestDispatcher.GetExchangePrincipal(OwaContext owaContext, ExchangePrincipal& exchangePrincipal) 
Microsoft.Exchange.Clients.Owa.Core.RequestDispatcher.PrepareRequestWithoutSession(OwaContext owaContext, UserContextCookie userContextCookie) 
Microsoft.Exchange.Clients.Owa.Core.RequestDispatcher.InternalDispatchRequest(OwaContext owaContext) 
Microsoft.Exchange.Clients.Owa.Core.RequestDispatcher.DispatchRequest(OwaContext owaContext) 
System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) 

Inner Exception 
Exception type: Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADTransientException 
Exception message: Could not find any available Global Catalog in forest xxx.local. 

Call stack 
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ConnectionPoolManager.GetConnection(ConnectionType connectionType, ADObjectId domain, String serverName, Int32 port, NetworkCredential credential) 
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ConnectionPoolManager.GetConnection(ConnectionType connectionType) 
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.GetConnection(String preferredServer, Boolean isWriteOperation, Boolean isNotifyOperation, ADObjectId& rootId) 
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.GetReadConnection(String preferredServer, ADObjectId& rootId) 
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.Find(ADObjectId rootId, String optionalBaseDN, ADObjectId readId, QueryScope scope, QueryFilter filter, SortBy sortBy, Int32 maxResults, IEnumerable`1 properties, CreateObjectDelegate objectCreator, CreateObjectsDelegate arrayCreator) 
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.Find(ADObjectId rootId, QueryScope scope, QueryFilter filter, SortBy sortBy, Int32 maxResults, IEnumerable`1 properties, CreateObjectDelegate objectCtor, CreateObjectsDelegate arrayCtor) 
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.Find[TResult](ADObjectId rootId, QueryScope scope, QueryFilter filter, SortBy sortBy, Int32 maxResults, IEnumerable`1 properties) 
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Recipient.ADRecipientSession.FindBySid(SecurityIdentifier sId) 
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.ExchangePrincipal.FromUserSid(ADRecipientSession recipientSession, SecurityIdentifier userSid)
```

Also I have notice that users with Outlook and Thunderbird with Exquilla, sometimes are unable to send mails, but doesnt show any conclusive error, just an error message saying that it is unable to send.

At least in server C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR with IIS logs, I dont have anything related.

Also at event logs I have several logs about this issue:

Event ID 2080: MSExchange ADAccess

```
Process MSEXCHANGEADTOPOLOGYSERVICE.EXE (PID=3028). Exchange Active Directory Provider has discovered the following servers with the following characteristics: 
 (Server name | Roles | Enabled | Reachability | Synchronized | GC capable | PDC | SACL right | Critical Data | Netlogon | OS Version) 
In-site:
xxx.xxx.local   CDG 1 6 7 1 0 1 1 7 1
 Out-of-site:
```

Event ID 4001: MSExchange System Attendant Mailbox

```
A transient failure has occurred. The problem may resolve itself in awhile. The service will retry in 56 seconds. Diagnostic information:

Could not find any available Global Catalog in forest xxx.local.
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADTransientException: Could not find any available Global Catalog in forest xxx.local.
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ConnectionPoolManager.GetConnection(ConnectionType connectionType, ADObjectId domain, String serverName, Int32 port, NetworkCredential credential)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ConnectionPoolManager.GetConnection(ConnectionType connectionType)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.GetConnection(String preferredServer, Boolean isWriteOperation, Boolean isNotifyOperation, ADObjectId& rootId)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.GetReadConnection(String preferredServer, ADObjectId& rootId)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.Find(ADObjectId rootId, String optionalBaseDN, ADObjectId readId, QueryScope scope, QueryFilter filter, SortBy sortBy, Int32 maxResults, IEnumerable`1 properties, CreateObjectDelegate objectCreator, CreateObjectsDelegate arrayCreator)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.Find(ADObjectId rootId, QueryScope scope, QueryFilter filter, SortBy sortBy, Int32 maxResults, IEnumerable`1 properties, CreateObjectDelegate objectCtor, CreateObjectsDelegate arrayCtor)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.Find[TResult](ADObjectId rootId, QueryScope scope, QueryFilter filter, SortBy sortBy, Int32 maxResults, IEnumerable`1 properties)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Recipient.ADRecipientSession.FindByLegacyExchangeDN(String legacyExchangeDN)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Servicelets.SystemAttendantMailbox.Servicelet.Work()
```

Event ID 1022: MSExchangeIS Mailbox Store

```
Logon Failure on database "First Storage Group\Mailbox Database" - Windows account NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE; mailbox /o=First Organization/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=user1.Error: -2147221231 Client Machine: xxx Client Process: edgetransport.exe Client ProcessId: 0 Client ApplicationId: Client=HUB 
Text
Event ID 1: MSExchange Autodiscover
Unhandled Exception "Could not find any available Global Catalog in forest xxx.local."Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ConnectionPoolManager.GetConnection(ConnectionType connectionType, ADObjectId domain, String serverName, Int32 port, NetworkCredential credential)   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ConnectionPoolManager.GetConnection(ConnectionType connectionType)   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.GetConnection(String preferredServer, Boolean isWriteOperation, Boolean isNotifyOperation, ADObjectId& rootId)   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.GetReadConnection(String preferredServer, ADObjectId& rootId)   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.Find(ADObjectId rootId, String optionalBaseDN, ADObjectId readId, QueryScope scope, QueryFilter filter, SortBy sortBy, Int32 maxResults, IEnumerable`1 properties, CreateObjectDelegate objectCreator, CreateObjectsDelegate arrayCreator)   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.Find(ADObjectId rootId, QueryScope scope, QueryFilter filter, SortBy sortBy, Int32 maxResults, IEnumerable`1 properties, CreateObjectDelegate objectCtor, CreateObjectsDelegate arrayCtor)   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.Find[TResult](ADObjectId rootId, QueryScope scope, QueryFilter filter, SortBy sortBy, Int32 maxResults, IEnumerable`1 properties)   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Recipient.ADRecipientSession.FindBySid(SecurityIdentifier sId)   at Microsoft.Exchange.Autodiscover.Providers.Outlook.OutlookAutoDiscoverProvider..ctor(RequestData requestData)
```

Event ID 1: MSExchange Autodiscover

```
Unhandled Exception "Could not find any available Global Catalog in forest xxx.local."Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ConnectionPoolManager.GetConnection(ConnectionType connectionType, ADObjectId domain, String serverName, Int32 port, NetworkCredential credential)   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ConnectionPoolManager.GetConnection(ConnectionType connectionType)   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.GetConnection(String preferredServer, Boolean isWriteOperation, Boolean isNotifyOperation, ADObjectId& rootId)   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.GetReadConnection(String preferredServer, ADObjectId& rootId)   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.Find(ADObjectId rootId, String optionalBaseDN, ADObjectId readId, QueryScope scope, QueryFilter filter, SortBy sortBy, Int32 maxResults, IEnumerable`1 properties, CreateObjectDelegate objectCreator, CreateObjectsDelegate arrayCreator)   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.Find(ADObjectId rootId, QueryScope scope, QueryFilter filter, SortBy sortBy, Int32 maxResults, IEnumerable`1 properties, CreateObjectDelegate objectCtor, CreateObjectsDelegate arrayCtor)   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADSession.Find[TResult](ADObjectId rootId, QueryScope scope, QueryFilter filter, SortBy sortBy, Int32 maxResults, IEnumerable`1 properties)   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Recipient.ADRecipientSession.FindBySid(SecurityIdentifier sId)   at Microsoft.Exchange.Autodiscover.Providers.Outlook.OutlookAutoDiscoverProvider..ctor(RequestData requestData)
```

Event Log order:

[image: Event Log order]

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

From error message "*Could not find any available Global Catalog in forest xxx.local*", it indicate that this issue may related to the status of GC.
Run **DCDiag** to analyzes the state of domain controllers.

Also, run below command to view the current DC, GC and static DC, GC:

```
Get-ExchangeServer -Status | fl Name,Current*,Static*
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have run the DCDiag and there are several errors at FrsEvent() and in SystemLog: https://pastebin.com/yNqCVCPv

Comment: Also when runing to see Exchange Server status, its only defined at Name, CurrentDomainControllers, CurrentGlobalCatalogs, CurrentConfigDomainController and there is nothing at StaticDomainControllers, StaticGlobalCatallgs, StaticConfigDomainController and StaticExcludedDomainControllers.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with your mailbox database, please check following points:

1. Make sure that all Exchange services are running
2. Run "[Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus](https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/how-to-use-get-mailboxdatabasecopystatus-command/)" to check the status of mailbox database.
3. Will you able login OWA or EAC in Exchange server with admin mailbox credentials?
4. Open Event Viewer and check if there any Exchange error messages in Application log, it will help to check issue in detail.